# Does anyone have an electronic copy of Waldspurger's "Sur les coefﬁcients de Fourier des formes modulaires de poids demi-entier"?

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

Is there an electronic copy of Waldspurger's paper "Sur les coefﬁcients de Fourier des formes modulaires de poids demi-entier" floating around the internet somewhere?  This appeared in J. Pures Math. Appliquees, Vol. 60 No. 4, in 1981.

Comment: Have you tried asking Waldspurger himself for an electronic copy? His email address is here: http://people.math.jussieu.fr/~waldspur/

Comment: There's really no reason not to write a title that says "Does anyone have an electronic copy of Waldspurger's paper "Sur les coefﬁcients de Fourier des formes modulaires de poids demi-entier"? " Titles in the form a question are strongly encouraged. 

Comment: True, so I made that the new title.

Comment: Surely anyone who asked this question on 25th Feb and got no answers has taken the trouble to go the library and make their own copy by now ;-)

Comment: @KB: Indeed I did. :)

Comment: That's true, but people are only going to internalize the fact that they should write useful titles if they are told so.

Comment: @BW: Are you saying I should reconsider the title for my forthcoming question, "On a theorem of Serre"? :P

Comment: Perhaps it would help non-french speakers like me if you could add a line or two about the article (what it is about) as the title of the paper is currently in French.

Comment: @David: It might have helped matters to include the page numbering, since the article is over 100 pages long (and has been very often cited, indicating its influence).     So far Elsevier's Science Direct have not reached back nearly so far in their archive to create searchable PDF files, though they now permit free access to older papers which have  PDF versions.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I needed it for another reason, so scanned it:
  http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/notes/Waldspurger.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Here's another version, single-paged and OCRed:

[http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~nsirolli/files/waldspurger.pdf](http://mate.dm.uba.ar/%7Ensirolli/files/waldspurger.pdf)