# Does anyone have access to a copy of Yury G. Teterin's 1984 (Russian) preprint "Representation of numbers by spinor genera"

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Encouraged by
[Does anyone have an electronic copy of Waldspurger's "Sur les coefﬁcients de Fourier des formes modulaires de poids demi-entier"?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16354/)
I realized I could ask for this rare item here.

Again, it is  Yury G. Teterin's 1984 (Russian) preprint "Representation of numbers by spinor genera."
For whatever reason (possibly length?) it never made it into the usual
Zapiski Nauchnykh Seminarov Leningradskogo Otdeleniya Matematicheskogo Instituta im. V. A. Steklova AN SSSR.

Let me give some detail. I do not know the number of pages. The preprint probably never appeared elsewhere, at least not under the same title. It was probably never translated into English. No American mathematics library admits to having it. The easiest place to find mention of the preprint is in Math Reviews MR0732548 (86d:11042) which is a review, by Oleg M. Fomenko, of Schulze-Pillot's 1984 "Thetareihen positiv definiter quadratischer Formen." (I do not know how to make the MR reference a link).

The preprint is mentioned in a later related item by the same author that has been translated, see

http://www.springerlink.com/content/t701481j73531761/

as well as one by Elena P. Golubeva

http://www.springerlink.com/content/w740g82624753417/

Finally, I have emailed Teterin with no result so far. If nothing happens for a long time I could write to O. M. Fomenko and see what happens. The three people in St. Petersburg that I have mentioned are

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=25046

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=22736

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?option_lang=eng&personid=33524

Well, thanks for any assistance. Individual replies are always welcome, one of my email addresses can be found through   http://www.ams.org/cml

EDIT, May 2021:  the pdf is on one of my websites

[KAP](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/)

direct link
[TETERIN](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ekap/Teterin_1984.pdf)

Let me point out that there are the strongly related Golubeva_Fomenko_1984.pdf in English translation, as well as Schulze_Pillot_1984_Darstellungsmasse.pdf and
Schulze_Pillot_1984_Thetareihen.pdf in these cases still in German. Also Math Reviews of most of the papers for which I lack a translation into English.

Comment: To make a link from MR number, click on “Make Link” under the title.
For example: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=732548
Of course, you can simply append http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=
in front of the MR number.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't think it worked the way I did it, but then I just know Latex in its original context and I need to push (Re)process math for any MO item I look at. But I see your link works.

Comment: When you obtain an electronic version of a paper that is not readily available for download to everybody, it is usually a good idea to post it on your web page so that other mathematicians can get it more easily in the future.  At least this is what I do with the papers that I scan: http://math.berkeley.edu/~pavlov/scans/

Comment: Dear Dmitri, evidently I put the pdf on the website on 26 April. But your comment shows that it would have mattered to point out on MO that I had posted the pdf, so I have edited the question to reflect that, also repeating the address.

Comment: The URL http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/forms.html is no longer working.

Comment: Was that paper by Teterin different from the one at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=znsl&paperid=5053&option_lang=eng?

Comment: @KConrad thanks; maybe, maybe not. The part about translated lattices makes a big difference, I imagine an earlier article discussed the original question, as in the Schulze-Pillot preprint, later articles, including some with Xu, in Contemporary Mathematics number 344  http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Schulze_Pillot_2004.pdf

Comment: Okay, I see now that the first reference in the bibliography of the paper I linked to is the 1984 paper you were seeking (correct title and year, nothing about translated lattices)

Comment: @KConrad it is now at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Teterin_1984.pdf    has an English abstract  I don't seem to have a full translation, I probably sent a pdf to my friend Dmitry, he used to read out loud (telephone) from Russian articles so I could have some idea whether I could use them.

Comment: Okay.  Edit the end of your post so it no longer says the article is missing from your page in 2021.

Comment: The two links to `springerlink.com` are broken.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist  alright. The "direct link"  to the Teterin (1984)   still seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yura Teterin left mathematics and POMI but may be he is reading his POMI e-mail http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~yuri/ 
also one can try to ask for a scan  at POMI editorial dept (Vera Simonova simonova@pdmi.ras.ru) or at the library lib@pdmi.ras.ru

Comment: Thank you, Nikolai. Given your news, the editorial department is the logical next step, and thank you for the contact information. I am also encouraged by seeing POMI preprints online, some not very long at all, in ps.gz format, one of yours in 2006 in both an English summary and Russian original, at  http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/preprint/index.html

Comment: I will look tomorrow. 


Comment: Dear Kolya, I got the preprint and sent you a reply. The article looks really good! At this point you may want to delete the comment above that shows one of your email addresses. I have never had any trouble, but there are supposedly automated programs called "bots" that search for such things. So I make it very easy for a real person to find my email address by searching in http://www.ams.org/cml  (and I put that in my Math Overflow "profile" for anyone to see), but I do not usually leave that address visible for very long.

Comment: I am taking the point of view that all my addresses are already cached by all bots:)

Comment: You are a wise man. I am humbled by your presence.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to call to the library of PDMI.
Most libraries copy materials and mail it to you for a reward.