# A copy of Vizing's classic article about list coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, paper-request

Does anyone know where I get a copy of Vizing's classic article about list coloring?

"V. G. Vizing, Coloring the vertices of a graph in prescribed colors, Metody Diskret. Anal. v Teorii Kodov i Schem, 29, 3-10, 1976. (In Russian)" ([MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=0498216))

Comment: intedr-library loan?

Comment: The underlying question has been answered before: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75238/how-to-locate-an-obscure-paper/.  Apart from the interlibrary loan, some of the best options might be to email Vizing directly (his email can be found here: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?&personid=26464&option_lang=eng) or to email some of the authors of at least 119 papers that cite him and ask for a copy: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=498216).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried all ways you posted, and I didn't get any success. Finally, I sent an email to the author a few day ago, but he has not answered me. I'll wait a while longer, and then I will try interlibrary loan. Thanks.

Comment: Related post on Mathematics SE: [Looking for a paper by Vizing (1976) introducing the list chromatic number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3957585/915354).

Comment: Also, it appears that Vizing [passed away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vadim_G._Vizing) in 2017...

Answer (score 2):

A copy of volume 29 of the journal *Metody diskretnogo analiza ...* is held by the British Library, according to their [catalog](http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01008522688). However, the details for this journal mentions

> **Rights:** Terms governing use: British Library not licensed to copy

This means that one cannot use their [On Demand](https://www.bl.uk/on-demand) service to request a copy of Vizing's article.

Instead, if you are based in the UK, you can request the journal volume to be delivered to one of their [reading rooms](https://www.bl.uk/visit/reading-rooms), and you could possibly make a scan of Vizing's article by yourself. You need a [Reader Pass](https://www.bl.uk/help/how-to-get-a-reader-pass) in order to avail yourself of this facility, though.

Another option is to request a scan of the relevant pages through their [Digitization Services](https://www.bl.uk/digitisation-services/services/ordering-images). When filling out their order form, you will have to provide the shelfmark of the journal, as well as the title of the article, the name of the author and other relevant details. The [catalog entry](http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01008522688) for the journal lists two shelfmarks: `(P) PA 00 -R(3)` and `0110.480000`. Either one can be supplied. Be sure to provide the author and title details as they are in the original Russian — for convenience, these should be В.Г.Визинг and Раскраска вершин графа в предписанные цвета, respectively. After you submit the form, you will receive an email within a few days requesting that you fill out a declaration so that the article can be provided under the library privilege exceptions. Once that is done, a scan of the article will be delivered to you by email in a few weeks. Of course, the service [does not come cheap](https://www.bl.uk/digitisation-services/pricing).

If you are based in the US, you may have some more options. A search on [WorldCat.org](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=n2%3A0136-1228) shows that several libraries in the US (and a handful in Europe other than the British Library) may hold copies of this journal. Some of these are listed by Thomas Lesgourgues in an [answer to 'Looking for a paper by Vizing (1976) introducing the list chromatic number'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957585/looking-for-a-paper-by-vizing-1976-introducing-the-list-chromatic-number/3957795#3957795) at Mathematics Stack Exchange. However, it [seems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957585/looking-for-a-paper-by-vizing-1976-introducing-the-list-chromatic-number#comment9189794_3957795) that not every library that lists this journal in their catalogue also holds volume 29 in particular.